# Google Drive Android Quickstart without user input

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I got Google Drive Android Quickstart working in my android app (This [one](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart)).

The problem I have is that i want to upload a file without allowing the user to see anything.
This part:

```
IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                            .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                            .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                            .setInitialDriveContents(result.getDriveContents())
                            .build(mGoogleApiClient);
                    try {
                        startIntentSenderForResult(
                                intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
                    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Failed to launch file chooser.");
                    }
```

...Is allowing the user to choose filename and placement in the drive and then uploads it. I want to make this automatic and invisible for the user but I don't know how.

Comment: Is that what you're looking for:
https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file#creating_files_programmatically?

Comment: That's it! I got it working. Thank you.